# how does libxml2 deal with fragmentation

Tags: c, memory, libxml2

I have added my custom allocators for libxml2 in a project and I see a list of alloc and free calls. What I am trying to check is how does libxml2 deal with fragmentation, if does at all. The program executable starts increasing memory and doesnt return it back to OS. There is a libxml2 documentation stating that this might happen in case the OS decides the memory being returned is too small and too much overhead for reusing it. My program uses a lot of small allocations using and freeing them. Rest of the application uses Thread based memory pools so there is no chance of leaking over there, these pools get reset on every iteration of handler calls. I have used the following functions to overwrite the default allocators just to check the allocations. Any help understanding this might be helpful. I have tried searching the website for memory fragmentation dealing with no success.

```
/* the function override the libxml2 default ones **/
void cfreeFunc(void* ptr);
void * cmallocFunc(size_t size);
void * cmallocAtomicFunc(size_t size);
void * creallocFunc(void *ptr, size_t size);
char * cstrdupFunc(const char *str);

xmlGcMemSetup(cfreeFunc, cmallocFunc, cmallocAtomicFunc, creallocFunc,
        cstrdupFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

libxml2 provides you with method to override it's memory management functions - what, if not this, could be done to address your issue? It's up to your functions side - and if you're using sbrk (or malloc which uses sbrk) - you're never returning memory. You could try using separate mmap for every single allocation, however in case of big amount of very small allocs it would significantly increase memory footprint. Better approach is to allocate buffers with mmap and use them as memory pads for future allocations.

Comment: my question was does libxml2 provide any kind of in build solution for minimizing fragmentation. I can use the overriding mechanism to plugin in jemalloc or some other allocator though to minimize it. libxml2 being used in so many project could have some internal solution for this. It does keep track of allocations and stuff.

Comment: Why should it? It asks for memory, your functions giving it. Then it asks to release these memory. If _your_ callee functions doesn't actually release it - what's question to libxml? Best way to do it is to allocate big block and then use it for further allocations - however, libxml definitevely doesn't have any ideas of how much memory will it require, and it already presented you with interface to make it yourself. I'm sure library developers shouldn't making changes for your very specific case, but rather provide you with interface to handle it.

Comment: they have default set of functions i was asking about those if they have some functionality of that sort. They have some functionality to detect memory leaks and overwrites. Anyways thanks a lot I appreciate this but this doesnt answer my question :(.